# Getting NaN error while running SVM in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am running the following code .

```
# Function for Stochastic Gradient Descent SVM
def SGD(k_fold,train_X,train_Y):
        """ Method to implement Multi-class SVM using 
            Stochastic Gradient Descent
        """

        from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
        scores_sgd = []

        for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
            train_X_cv = train_X[train_indices]
            train_Y_cv = train_Y[train_indices]

            test_X_cv  = train_X[test_indices]
            test_Y_cv  = train_Y[test_indices]

            sgd = SGDClassifier( loss = 'hinge', penalty = 'l2' )
            scores_sgd.append( sgd.fit( train_X_cv, train_Y_cv ).score( test_X_cv, test_Y_cv ) )

        print( "The mean accuracy of Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier on CV data is:", np.mean( scores_sgd ) )

        return sgd
```

This is how my **`k_folds`** data look like:

```
for a,b in k_fold:
    print len(a), len(b)
```

I even checked my **`train_X`** and **`train_Y`** for **`NaN`**

```
>>> numpy.isnan( train_X ).any()
False
```

But still I am getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a2f71582edd0> in <module>()
      1 # Running SGD. and RF
      2 
----> 3 sgd=SGD(k_fold,train_X,train_Y)
      4 #rf=RF(k_fold,train_X,train_Y)

<ipython-input-12-7e3b6395f3d6> in SGD(k_fold, train_X, train_Y)
     62 
     63             sgd=SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',penalty='l2')
---> 64             scores_sgd.append(sgd.fit(train_X_cv,train_Y_cv).score(test_X_cv,test_Y_cv))
     65 
     66         print("The mean accuracy of Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier on CV data is:", np.mean(scores_sgd))

/Users/mtripathi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.pyc in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, class_weight, sample_weight)
    562                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
    563                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
--> 564                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    565 
    566 

/Users/mtripathi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    401             self.classes_ = None
    402 
--> 403         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    404         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    405 

/Users/mtripathi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric)
    448     else:
    449         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 450         _assert_all_finite(y)
    451     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
    452         y = y.astype(np.float64)

/Users/  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a2f71582edd0> in <module>()
      1 # Running SGD. and RF
      2 
----> 3 sgd=SGD(k_fold,train_X,train_Y)
      4 #rf=RF(k_fold,train_X,train_Y)

<ipython-input-12-7e3b6395f3d6> in SGD(k_fold, train_X, train_Y)
     62 
     63             sgd=SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',penalty='l2')
---> 64             scores_sgd.append(sgd.fit(train_X_cv,train_Y_cv).score(test_X_cv,test_Y_cv))
     65 
     66         print("The mean accuracy of Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier on CV data is:", np.mean(scores_sgd))

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.pyc in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, class_weight, sample_weight)
    562                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
    563                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
--> 564                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    565 
    566 

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    401             self.classes_ = None
    402 
--> 403         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    404         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    405 

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric)
    448     else:
    449         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 450         _assert_all_finite(y)
    451     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
    452         y = y.astype(np.float64)

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
     50             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     51         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 52                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     53 
     54 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').tr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
     50             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     51         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 52                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     53 
     54 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Please help. I am **`random forest`** but it is killing the kernel I don't know why.

Comment: You focus on NaN, but the error also mentions large or infinite values. Can you give the output of `numpy.max(train_Y)` ?

Answer (score 0):

### If struggling with non-sanitized DataSET:

```
np.nan_to_num( ... ).astype( np.float32 ) # may help to prototope the methods


"""
Replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers.

Returns an array or scalar replacing Not a Number (NaN) with zero,
(positive) infinity with a very large number and negative infinity
with a very small (or negative) number.

Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    Input data.

Returns
-------
out : ndarray, float
    Array with the same shape as `x` and dtype of the element in `x`  with
    the greatest precision. NaN is replaced by zero, and infinity
    (-infinity) is replaced by the largest (smallest or most negative)
    floating point value that fits in the output dtype. All finite numbers
    are upcast to the output dtype (default float64).

See Also
--------
isinf    : Shows which elements are negative or negative infinity.
isneginf : Shows which elements are negative infinity.
isposinf : Shows which elements are positive infinity.
isnan    : Shows which elements are Not a Number (NaN).
isfinite : Shows which elements are finite (not NaN, not infinity)

Notes
-----
Numpy uses the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point for Arithmetic
(IEEE 754). This means that Not a Number is not equivalent to infinity.


Examples
--------
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=8)
>>> x = np.array([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan, -128, 128])
>>> np.nan_to_num(x)
array([  1.79769313e+308,  -1.79769313e+308,   0.00000000e+000,
        -1.28000000e+002,   1.28000000e+002])

"""
```

### Once O/S starts shoot-down RandomForest / SVM-kernel processing

1 ) Revise your available ( O/S dependent ) **RAM-size / virtual-memory management** options and upgrade paths possible.

2 ) Reduce your DataSET representation, going from **`np.float64`** down to **`np.float32`**

3 ) Avoid in-RAM duplicates and avoid python-memory-manager reluctance to return mem-allocs to O/S re-use, possibly leading to going into **`numpy`** non-in-RAM matrix representations ( memory-mapped files ).

4 ) Finally, near in-RAM boundary, may benefit from using **`RandomForest`** incremental build-up ( **`warm = True`** )

If your localhost O/S does not permit the sizes needed, move your processing to different O/S platform / cloud-hosted processing, where both RAM-size & O/S permits bigger in-RAM objects being processed.

---

### A small utility for getting a view on `python`'s memory use

```
def getExtMemoryUsed():                                # msMOD.DEBUG.self ( ref. 2GB Memory Crashes in python + wXP /3GB [BOOT.ini]-options.............................................................
    import os, psutil
    aMemoryINFO     = psutil.Process( os.getpid() ).get_ext_memory_info()
    anItemLIST      = [ ( "num_page_faults",    "x"  ),
                        ( "peak_wset",          "MB" ),
                        ( "wset",               "MB" ),
                        ( "peak_paged_pool",    "MB" ),
                        ( "paged_pool",         "MB" ),
                        ( "peak_nonpaged_pool", "MB" ),
                        ( "nonpaged_pool",      "MB" ),
                        ( "pagefile",           "MB" ),
                        ( "peak_pagefile",      "MB" ),
                        ( "private",            "MB" )
                        ]
    aListOfShowIDs  = [ 8, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 ]
    for i, id in enumerate( aListOfShowIDs[:-1] ):
        print     "{0: > 16.3f} {2:_>20s} {1: >3s} ".format(     aMemoryINFO[id] / float( 2**20 ), anItemLIST[id][1], anItemLIST[id][0] )
    print     "                 {2:_>20s} {0: >11d} x\n".format( aMemoryINFO[ 0],                                 "", anItemLIST[ 0][0] )

    """
    |>>> getExtMemoryUsed()
        1534.012 _______peak_pagefile  MB
        1195.777 ____________pagefile  MB
        1195.777 _____________private  MB
        1119.109 ___________peak_wset  MB
         662.457 ________________wset  MB
           0.321 _____peak_paged_pool  MB
           0.321 __________paged_pool  MB
           0.084 __peak_nonpaged_pool  MB
           0.083 _______nonpaged_pool  MB
                 _____num_page_faults     3727767 x

pextmem(num_page_faults=3727767, peak_wset=1173471232, wset=694636544, peak_paged_pool=336316, paged_pool=336172, peak_nonpaged_pool=87968, nonpaged_pool=87480, pagefile=1253863424, peak_pagefile=1608527872, private=1253863424)
    """
    return aMemoryINFO
```

This tiny code requires less memory than a fully fledged memory-profiler add-on while helps you diagnose how near / how far from the in-RAM boundary your code has already got.

---

<sub>For hawkish pythoneers, the post intentionally uses non-PEP-8 source code formatting as it is authors experience that during a learning phase, code read-ability improves the focus on task solution and helps getting used to the underlying concepts rather than to spend efforts on formally adhering typography. Hope the principle of providing help is respected and the non-PEP-8 styling format is forgiven in the name of the ease of reading.</sub>